# Cannot open jupyter notebook

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, python

After accessing Linux server by ssh in my notebook(Window 10)
and then opening 'jupyter notebook'.
The following problem occured.
[image]
Like this picture

How can I solve this problem. I need your help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your notebook server is running on the Linux machine. The full trace from the server would be useful (could you provide it?) but the message is informing you that the Linux server has no web browser available for the server to display its output.

Depending on the setup of your server (and the full trace should show this), you may be able to access the notebook from a browser running on your windows machine, at an address such as:

```
http://my-linux-server.org:8888
```

This address should appear in the trace output. For example, when I run a notebook myself, I get:

```
[I 12:06:11.901 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
[I 12:06:11.901 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 12:06:11.901 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=b2f4cb6d2e868d6b12500e43c835bcddd21155d7df78052d
[I 12:06:11.901 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=b2f4cb6d2e868d6b12500e43c835bcddd21155d7df78052d
[I 12:06:11.901 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 12:06:11.933 NotebookApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-17371-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=b2f4cb6d2e868d6b12500e43c835bcddd21155d7df78052d
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=b2f4cb6d2e868d6b12500e43c835bcddd21155d7df78052d
```

Here,

```
http://localhost:8888/?token=b2f4cb6d2e868d6b12500e43c835bcddd21155d7df78052d
```

is the address I use to access the server. By default, the notebook server doesn't allow access from other addresses, but editing the file ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py to include the line:

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
```

allows access from any IP. Use a more restrictive IP address instead of '0.0.0.0' to ensure no other user uses your session.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the parameter `--no-browser` when launching the notebook server.